# Virtual environment for PowerShell possible?

Tags: windows, powershell, script

Imagine you want to install a PowerShell module. For that you might need Administrator access.
Then, you will change the system globally maybe just for a test.
Is it possible to tell PowerShell to use an isolated configuration environment similar like you do with venv in Python?

Comment: short of a running a full VM, i think you are stick with using one of the container images. interestingly, there are images for docker containers ... but not for windows containers. >>> PowerShell - Docker Hub — https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-powershell

Answer (score 2):

Not a sandbox/virtual environment, but to avoid installing for everybody/needing admin permissions:

`Install-Module ModuleName -Scope CurrentUser`

> The CurrentUser installs modules in a location that is accessible only
> to the current user of the computer. For example:
>
> $home\Documents\PowerShell\Modules

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module

Answer (score 1):

You may use the (now) free and open-source
[Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/),
for doing all your manipulations in a sandbox that can be discarded by
a click.

[Windows Sandbox](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-kernel-internals/windows-sandbox/ba-p/301849)
is Microsoft's own sandbox product, which might be less handy than Sandboxie,
but perhaps better integrated into Windows.

Comment: this is very interesting! in the docs they say it's a *desktop* environment; now is it possible to run it in a headless environment, just using PowerShell similarly to Docker containers?

Answer (score 0):

Also, remember that modules can be installed on a central server, then one can use implicit remoting to use them. No need to ever install a module locally if you don't want to. On that central server, you can downlaod all the PSGallery modules, internal repo, and set your environment to install from there as well as update from them

These using remote modules, via implicit/explicit Powershell Remoting...

```
New-PSSEssion
Enter-PSSEssion
```

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/an-introduction-to-powershell-remoting-part-four-sessions-and-implicit-remoting
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_faq

... is a well-documtned thing for ADDS...

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-active-directory-cmdlets-without-installing-any-software
  ...
  Exchange, O365, Azure etc., but not really explicitly talked about for other modules.

You, establish a remote session and proxy the module cmdlets to your host, thus they are only available as long as you are in the session that exists.

You can also, from the remote server, just import a module via a UNC path.

- https://network-nick.blogspot.com/2015/08/import-powershell-module-from-unc-path.html